# Flutter run command is not working on my mac

Tags: macos, flutter, web, terminal, flutter-test

I am going to build flutter app on mac now.
I set up it as tutorial guide.
Then I can't run "Flutter run" command now
I got this error from terminal.
[image]

How can I resolve it.
I need your help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the flutter path in the bin.

You must edit it to use the flutter cmd globally.

You can refer to the official docs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path).

Or, if you don't understand it, proceed as below -

1. Open the Terminal App, and type `$ vim ~/.zshrc`
2. It will open a VIM file in the Terminal itself.
3. Type 'i' to start editing this file.
4. Paste this line there - `export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin"`
5. Set the Path to flutter directory (where you placed the folder)
6. Type `:wq!`
7. Close the terminal
8. Open a new terminal window.
9. Run the command `$ flutter --version`

Now you will see the version of FLutter you have installed and also use the `$flutter run` command.